# How to achieve below design in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

can some one please help me to achieve the same design as above

Here is my code please have a look into that!

```
<TabView>
                    {Buttons.map((each, i) => {
                        return(
                            <ButtonTabView color={each.color}>
                                <ButtonText color={each.color}>{each.title}</ButtonText>
                            </ButtonTabView>
                        )
                    })}
                    </TabView>


export const TabView = styled.View`
    flexDirection: row;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: space-around;
`;
export const ButtonTabView = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-color: ${props => props.color};
    justify-content: center;
`;
export const ButtonText = styled.Text`
    color: ${props => props.color};
    font-family: ${Theme.fontFamily.regular};
    font-size: ${Theme.fontSize.semiRegular};
`;
```

I'm getting problem to achieve same design am I missing any styling property here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to replace your `TabView` here,

```
export const TabView = styled.View`
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: space-around;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you need to add one more property to it, add `flex-wrap: wrap` in `TabView` style. The default behaviour of `flexWrap` is `nowrap`. Take a look at the document [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#flexwrap).

Also, you might need to consider `justifyContent`, as per your shared code which is `space-around`, that does not meet the requirement you have shared. Instead, `flex-start` will mimic the design you have shared.

Put some margin around the `ButtonTabView` component.

**Note:** It's clear that you are using `Styled Component`, but in the shared code you have written `flexDirection`, which need to be changed to `flex-direction`.

Hope this will help!